# How correctly overload conversion from base class to inherit

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-conversion, operator-overloading, overloading

I think my question is simple and clear:

I have base class AbstractMatrix, and subclass of it Matrix, and I want to make simple conversion:

```
namespace mtrx {
/* mycode */
    class AbstractMatrix {
        public:
        /* -//- */
        operator Matrix ();
        /* -//- */
    }
    class Matrix : public AbstractMatrix {
    /* -//- */
    }
}
```

AbstractMatrix.cpp:

```
AbstractMatrix::operator Matrix(){
    return Matrix(data);
}
```

compiler gives message:

```
Matrix.h:39:12: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Matrix’
   operator Matrix ();
            ^
```

What I do wrong? 
Is it possible to make such conversions? I think yes, because I just want make constructor based on superclass but without any boring syntax and I need it implicit

Thank you

Comment: I'm more curious about why you need to do this? What is the problem the operator is supposed to solve? Can't you have a virtual "getter" function which returns an `AbstractMatrix` pointer? Or perhaps use [the CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to know the child class?

Comment: As for your problem, you *do* know that symbols must be declared (or sometimes even defined) *before* you use the symbols?

Comment: for example for foo(Matrix A); if I do something like this foo(B) where B is AbstractMatrix, B would be conversed to Matrix class. Thank you for advice,I have recently started learn C++ and I will read about virtual functions and CRTP, may be it'll help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should simply provide a *forward declaration*:

```
namespace mtrx {

    class Matrix; // <=== here

    class AbstractMatrix {
        public:
        operator Matrix ();
    };

    class Matrix : public AbstractMatrix {

    };

}
```

to make `Matrix` visible for `AbstractMatrix` class.

---

P.S. You should probably reconsider your design, because having a conversion operator to convert base class to derived class looks weird for me.

Comment: Oh, I tried to do it above namespace. About design yes, I think your remark is appropriate, but it was more about curious why it doesn't work